# UIReferenceLibraryViewController in UIPopovercontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I was recommended to use a UIPopovercontroller in order to display my UIReferenceLIbraryViewController so that the dictionary does not take up the entire screen when I click my UIButton "search"

What I have is a UITextField that takes in the string/word, a button that will search it and pull up the UIReferenceLibraryViewController.

I'm having problems using a popovercontroller to do this. When I tried it, the button doesn't respond. Any tips/help??

edit:

[UIReferenceLibraryViewController in a popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643742/uireferencelibraryviewcontroller-in-subview)

It was originally

```
  if([UIReferenceLibraryViewController dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:searchTerm])
    {

        UIReferenceLibraryViewController *referenceLibraryVC = [[UIReferenceLibraryViewController alloc] initWithTerm:searchTerm];

        [self presentModalViewController:referenceLibraryVC animated:YES]; 

            }
```

which makes it take up the entire ipad screen

Does UIReferenceLIbraryViewController have initWithFrame? that solution didn't seem to work for me either

Comment: Post code how you tried to open the popover. Make sure to read the documentation. A popover has to be retained while it is presented. Once it is dismissed, you can release it.

Comment: Thanks Leo, I actually just figured it out. I wasn't adding the popover method to the write IBAction

Comment: Nice. Please post an answer to the problem and accept your answer.

Comment: If you solved this yourself you should delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Leo Nathan's help, it works now.

```
 self.masterPopOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:referenceLibraryVC];
        [self.masterPopOverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:[sender superview] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

I didn't connect it correctly in the XIB file and it wasn't implemented in the correct place in the IBAction for ButtonPress